# Can't get Javac to work on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile with javac on Snow Leopard through the command line. I have Xcode installed. I am just using a simple Hello World file, it works in Eclipse but I can't get it to work using javac.
javac -version returns javac 1.6.0_17

HelloWorld.java

```
public class HelloWorld
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
 String message = "Welcome to Java!";
        System.out.println(message);
   }
}
```

I type: javac HelloWorld.java

and get the following error.

```
HelloWorld.java:1: class, interface, or enum expected
public class HelloWorld 
^
1 error
```

and...

javac -cp . HelloWorld.java

returns the same.

echo $CLASSPATH just returns blank.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you using UTF-8 perhaps, with a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start of the file? Perhaps that's confusing javac?

Have a look at the file with a hex editor to see what it looks like.

Comment: It is UTF-8, what should I change it to?

Comment: ok, I changed it to Wester (Mac OS Roman) and it worked! Thank you, but what if I do want to use UTF-8? How would I do that?

Comment: You could leave it at UTF-8, and run `javac -encoding UTF-8 ...` Otherwise, it uses the platform default.

Comment: @elguapo-85: I would personally follow chris_l's recommendation of specifying it explicitly on the command line: UTF-8 is a generally good choice for text files.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS X 10.5.8, the default `file.encoding` is `MacRoman`. Eclipse uses this as its default, but that default may be changed in `Eclipse > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text file encoding`, as well as in each project's properties. In NetBeans, a similar setting is available in each project's properties.
[image: EclipseWorkspace]

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible to change the default encoding of Mac OS X or will this cause problems?

Comment: @elguapo-85: I never tried. I use MacRoman in Eclipse and UTF-8 in BetBeans. Terminal is set to UTF-8, and I specify `-encoding` when it matters, as @chris_l & @Jon Skeet suggested in comments.